# Connecting to snowflake in django using proxy

Tags: django, database, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have deployed my django app on heroku and I want to connect to snowflake. But whenever I redeploy, IP changes and my app is not able to connect to snowflake(IP whitelisting issue). I have tried to use `fixie` as a proxy so that when I connect to **snowflake**, my IP doesnt change and I don't need to get it whitelisted. Below are two code snippets I have been using to connect to `snowflake`. But my app keeps trying to connect using my network IP and not the proxy.

**MY IMPORTS:**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
import requests
import snowflake
import snowflake.connector
```

**snippet 1:**

```
engine = create_engine(
         'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database}/{schema}'.format(
             user=connection_details["user"],
             password=connection_details["pw"],
             account=connection_details["account"],
             database=connection_details["database"],
             schema=connection_details["schema"],
             ),
             connect_args={
                 'proxy': 'http://fixie:kT8kuyNpPbrbdx@velodroll.usefixie.com:80'
             })
```

**snippet 2:**

```
engine = snowflake.connector.connect(user=connection_details["user"],password=connection_details["pw"],account=connection_details["account"],database=connection_details["database"],schema=connection_details["schema"],connect_args={'proxy': 'http://fixie:kT8djczxc14@velodsad.usefixie.com:80'})
```

**and the error i keep getting :**

> snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: pv40812.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com:443. IP address 169.169.169.69 is not allowed to access Snowflake. Contact your account administrator. For more information about this error, go to https://community.snowflake.com/s/ip-xxxxxxxxxxxx-is-not-allowed-to-access.

I tried to connect to snowflake through fixie proxy but it keeps ignoring it

Answer (score 1):

Proxy server parameters are not supported. Instead, use the supported environment variables to configure a proxy server.

Linux or macOS:

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://username:password@proxyserver.company.com:80'
export HTTPS_PROXY='http://username:password@proxyserver.company.com:80'
```

Windows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyserver.company.com:80
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyserver.company.com:80
```

For more information, have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/sqlalchemy#proxy-server-configuration)